# How write logs to file with unicorn config

Tags: logging, fastapi, uvicorn

Its my uvicorn `log_config.yaml`. All works perfect untill i add logging to file. Its says to me

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 0)
```

I try different variations of logging (`FileHandler`,`RotateHandler`) but same issue raised.

```
version: 1
disable_existing_loggers: False
formatters:
  default:
    "()": uvicorn.logging.DefaultFormatter
    format: '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
  access:
    "()": uvicorn.logging.AccessFormatter
    format: "[%(asctime)s %(process)d:%(threadName)s] %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s | %(filename)s:%(lineno)d"
handlers:
  default:
    formatter: default
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    stream: ext://sys.stderr

  access:
    formatter: access
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    stream: ext://sys.stdout
    
  file_handler:
    class: logging.FileHandler
    level: INFO
    formatter: access
    filename: info.log
    encoding: utf8
    mode: a

loggers:
  uvicorn.error:
    level: INFO
    handlers: [default]
    propagate: no

  uvicorn.access:
    level: INFO
    handlers: [access]
    propagate: no
```

Comment: What version of `uvicorn` are you using? I can load your configuration using `version: 0.20.0` without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since you specified all information about formatter in the `yaml` file you have no formatter object.

The python class for `logging.FileHandler` does not have an argument called `formatter` and thus custom formats cannot be used.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.FileHandler

Saying this, you *can* use the `formatter: default` as it's registered being the `DefaultFormatter`

Answer (score 0):

change the formatter of the file handler to use uvicorn's **default**

```
handlers:
...

  file_handler:
    class: logging.FileHandler
    level: INFO
    formatter: default
    filename: info.log
    encoding: utf8
    mode: a
```